# How to reconfigure hostname on Arch Linux so the pacman command works properly

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, hostname

I just finished installing Arch Linux on my computer to the point where I can boot my system without
the thumb drive.  After rebooting I started making some adjustments and quickly realized that my pacman
command no longer works correctly and I am not sure why.  At first, I thought that I might not be connected
to the internet anymore but I ran several successful pin commands that indicate I am still connected
to the internet.  For example, if I try to install the microcode for my intel processor I get the following errors.  I am only showing a few of the errors, but it appears that it has tried every site on my mirror
list and failed them all.  I start by typing the command;

```
sudo pacman -S intel-ucode
```

Which yields

```
resolving dependencies
looking for conflicting packages…

packages (1) intel-code-20210216-1

total Download Size: 2.67 MiB
total Installed Size: 3.46 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

I press enter to accept the default of yes and I get the following errors.  Again this only shows the errors
for some of the sites, but it appears it is running through all the sites on the mirror list.

```
error: failed retrieving file ‘intel-code-20210216-1-any.pkg.tar.zst’ from www.caco.ic.unicap.br : Could not resolve host: www.caco.ic.unicamp.br
error: failed retrieving file ‘intel-code-20210216-1-any.pkg.tar.zst’ from ftp.agdsn.de : Could not resolve host: ftp.agdsn.de
error: failed retrieving file ‘intel-code-20210216-1-any.pkg.tar.zst’ from mirror.darklinux.uk : Could not resolve host: mirror.darklinux.uk
error: failed retrieving file ‘intel-code-20210216-1-any.pkg.tar.zst’ from mirror.surf : Could not resolve host: mirror.surf.  
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid url for server)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded
```

This began to occur after I set my hostname as `webbmachine` using the command `hostnamectl set-hostname webbmachine`.  I have also verified that my hostname is reflected in the `/etc/hostname` file and the `/etc/hosts` file also reflects the correct information with the following format.

```
# Static table lookup for hostnames
# See hosts(5) for details
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 webbmachine
```

I think the issue is with how my hostname is set up, but I am not sure.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does running `sudo pacman -Sy` fix it? What is the output of `ping -c1 8.8.8.8` (please [edit] that into your question)?

Comment: I think the second part is in my question. I did ping several web sites and it responded as expected with all packets received.  I did try sudi pacman -Sy as well and that did not fix the issue.

Comment: I don't see the word "ping" anywhere in your question so I don't know what you mean by "it is in my question". In any case, I asked for the _output_ of a specific `ping` command (that's one of Google's DNS servers). The output would help us eliminate some possible causes. But if you also pinged a webpage by name, then please add that detail to your question too. If you have determined that the issue is only with `pacman` and other internet uses work, tell us that too.

Comment: I presume the problem lies in the mirror that not work properly, [see](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/mirrors#Enabling_a_specific_mirror). Let's see if your problem persists after add or change the mirror.

Answer (score 0):

the `could not resolve host` error looks a lot like some DNS problem, which might be caused by the webbmachine config

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. This feels more like a comment than an answer. How would the OP check if it is a DNS problem (you could suggest `ping`ing something)? How would the webmachine config affect it? What is the "webmachine config"? How would you suggest that the OP fix it? As it stands, this isn't answering the question so please either expand it into an actual answer or delete it.

Comment: @Osleep I had a similar comment earlier. What do you think I should be looking for in the config file?